# Gatsby error when creating a new route: Preparing requested page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I setup a new Gatsby project through the installer but when I try to create a new file in `/src/pages`, but if then I go to that route, the browser says

> Preparing requested page

in loop. In the browser console it outputs:

```
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: We couldn't find the correct component chunk with the name "component---src-pages-home-js" (anonymous function) (loader.js:45) promiseReactionJob
```

This is my home.js (in a normal React environment works perfectly):

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <title>Test</title>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Project structure:

```
pages
 - 404.js
 - index.js
 - second.js
```

What could be the problem? I already tried to reinstall Gatsby again and tried cleaning caches or making another file, with a different file names. The file is seen by Gatsby because if I try to access the route without creating the file, it gives me the 404 page.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

If you're using a Mac with M1 Chip, make sure you installed Gatsby with Rosetta!

Comment: I have the problem in Safari, none of the solutions work. No problems in Chrome though.

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome seem not to have this problem. Also (unlike safari) the page reloads on save in `gatsby develop` sessions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried renaming your `home.js` to `index.js`?

After that, clean the cache by `gatsby clean`.

Comment: Yes, I just tried to rename and it works perfectly. And now, the other page that previously was `index.js` (I renamed to `second.js`) gives the error that I mentioned above if I go to `localhost:8000/second`. It's like if I can't create a new route.

Comment: Can you share the project's structure? At least the `/pages` folder. Be careful when importing components, don't import pages between them, import just the components.

Comment: Yes, the project is simple because I just created it (it's the first time that I use Gatsby):
(Structure added as update in the question)

`404.js` and `index` contains the default code. `second`, contains the code that I write above.

Comment: Is the second.js file exporting a valid React component? (Capitalized, etc)

Comment: Yes, of course. I also tried to copy the `index.js` content (changing the component name, obviously) to `second.js`

Comment: I'm running out of ideas... I would suggest a fresh (re)install. Can you share the repo?

Comment: Ok, I think that I resolved... I'm using new Silicon Mac M1 and I reinstalled Gatsby with Rosetta, now code is working... The only problem is that when I create a new route I have to run `gatsby clean` before accessing to the new page, but is fine.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Personally, I always use `gatsby clean` in my own `gatsby develop` command to avoid the most common issues while coding sites. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvotingthe answer to close the issue

Answer (score 19):

Also hit the same problem with M1 MacBook Air when adding pages to Gatsby sample project.  The solution (found elsewhere) was to empty the browser cache.

Answer (score 8):

This may be due to data in your browser cache. Clear the cache in Safari with `Option + Command + E`

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue for me. Using it in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to clear my entire cache so I opened a new private window and that worked for me